# Return variable from method in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Something like this

```
var joined = function(arr) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i in arr) {
        var u = DB.getUser(arr[i].user_id, function(user) {
            return user;
        });
        arr[i].user = u;
        res = arr[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

I need to get user variable from DB.getUser scope.

Comment: Let me guess. `DB.getUser` is async?

Comment: You could also thing about implementing a `getUsers` function. MongoDB has a `$in` selector which allows you to fetch multiple documents in one query. This should be faster and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is just inserted some comments into you code to help understand the async flow:

```
var joined = function(arr) {
    // Timestamp: 0
    var res = [];
    for (var i in arr) {
        // Timestamp: 1
        var u = DB.getUser(arr[i].user_id, function(user) {
            // Timestamp 4 ... length of arr
            // user contains what you are looking for
            // but this is not return to u, because we passed that a long time ago
            return user;
        });
        // u is null or undefined, because DB.getUser returns nothing
        // is a async function, you need wait for the callback
        arr[i].user = u;
        // Timestamp: 2 return useless arr
        res = arr[i];
    }
    // Timestamp: 3 again, return a useless array
    return res;
}
```

**Edit:**

You need to this before you pass everything to the template, e.g.:

```
var joined = function(arr, doneCallback) {
    var res = []
    var count = arr.length;
    for (var i in arr) {
        DB.getUser(arr[i].user_id, function(user) {
            count--;
            res.push(user);
            if (count == 0) {
                doneCallback(res);
            }
        })
    }
}

joined(somedata, function(mydata) {
    render(template, mydata)
});
```

Take a look at some flow control libraries. (My favorite [async](https://github.com/caolan/async))

Comment: You should do it recursively instead of using a loop - the count variable wont change until the callback is fired.

Comment: @eosterberg: That is the idea. Before the callback is fired there is no result. Therefore we should wait until the last result comes back / the last callback is fired.

Comment: @TheHippo: What if one of the users takes a very long time to get? I meant the count variable in the anonymous callback, not the one in the args.

Comment: @eosterberg: The same thing applies to your own answer ;-) Usually a query will return a time out error, which has to be fetched and handled. I assumed this will happen in the `getUser` function itself.

Comment: @TheHippo: Now I got it! Your answer works fine, and its probably easier to read than mine.

Comment: @eosterberg Glad I could help. As proposed he should write a query that fetches all user. If not it is probably useful to use some flow control library which hides all the counting and managing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getJoinedAndDoSomeThingWithThem = function(ids) {
var joined = [];
var i = 0;

var getAUser = function () {
    DB.getUser(ids[i].user_id, function(user) {
        joined.push(user);
        i++;
        if (i == ids.length -1) {
            doSomeThingWithTheResult(joined);
            return;
        }
        getAUser();
    });
}
getAUser();
}
```

Comment: Despite the code isn't complete, this probably won't work for the same issue.

Comment: You're right, I've misread that. (And therefore deleted my comment shortly after.)